# Polymorphic engines in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, assembly, polymorphism

I stumbled across polymorphic engines and I don't know anything about them. However, I am curious about how they are written. Every example that I've looked up writes them in assembly, my assembly is not good at all; I know just a few instructions here and there but not that well. On the other hand, I am good in C and C++.

I am familiar with the concept of polymorphism in C++ but after reading about polymorphic engines, I am assuming that they are different from the polymorphism in C++.

How can techniques such as using `virtual` keyword in C++ be used to obfuscate or encrypt the code in an application?

Comment: sorry.. do you mean a code obfuscator or what?

Comment: yeah, though i'm not sure if they're the same thing.

Comment: That stuff is commonly used to trick antiviruses and/or circumvent signature checkers. You can almost always express a series of instructions with a longer series of instructions that does the same thing

Comment: so is it possible to do that in c/c++?

Comment: Sure, but this is a broad, broad question. And I don't have a suggestion for a tutorial/resources right now (that is off-topic here too)

Comment: let me try and narrow down the question.

Comment: Maybe this question would be more fitting to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: so I should delete it from here and ask it over there?

Comment: This question should be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com, but was already cross-posted there.

Comment: I'd recommend you first attempt to understand how an executable packers (eg. UPX http://upx.sourceforge.net/) work. See this RE question about simple open source Windows packers: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/is-there-any-simple-open-source-windows-packer You can then also write your own packer (using eg. RLE) to get started.

Comment: thanks for those links @nrz

Comment: @KilianFoth, i could delete the question over there and then you could migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a program has to be modified you can go either modifying the source code or modifying the compiled executable.

The first approach is awful (in my opinion) because:

- A source file is subject to a lot of optimizations in the compilation processes. So two source files slightly different from each other could produce the same object code.
- If you need your program to be self modifying you will have to carry with all the tools needed to build it. (Something like carrying a candy factory with you just for the case you want a candy of a different flavor in your trip)
- ...

Notice that I'm talking here about compiled languages as the use of C or C++ in your question suggests. For interpreted languages the first approach is the obvious one.

In your case, the second makes more sense but it is strictly related to the machine code of the target machine.

So my point is: if you want to implement a program or routine that is able to produce a modified version of other program or a modified version of itself you can implement it in Assembly, C, C++ or any other language but in all cases you have to be proficient in your target machine's assembly language and machine code.

I recommend you to research more. This topic is broad. In the case you decide to go on, I can say that Assembly won't be the biggest dragon to beat.

Comment: I like how you've put your answer but I still don't get how a program can be self-modifying or polymorphic, is the decryption routine put in the source code?

Comment: Yes, the decryption/encryption or obfuscation routines can be put in the source code but they're meant to modify the compiled code.

Comment: ... in-memory or in disk.

Comment: this stuff seems difficult, I wonder if you could post a simple encryption/decryption routine? Guess I should also study cryptography..

Comment: This is a broad topic, @Hawk. An SO question won't clear all your doubts. Here you can see an example: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/writing-self-modifying-code-part-1/